# can an autogas/lpg system damage the 6.2l v8 corvette engine?

Tags: engine, performance, lpg

for example, we have recently bought a 2008 chevrolet corvette from the turkish customs, and we converted our corvette to autogas / liquefied petroleum gas in a turkish conversion shop, with liquefied petroleum gas conversion kit supplied by italian company lovato.

will there be a damage to the engine and/or parts? will performance of the car can down with lpg?

Answer (score 3):

From http://lpgautoconversions.co.uk/faq/index.php:

> Does LPG Autogas hurt the engine?
>
> No. In fact quite the contrary. As the fuel is a gas it mixes better with air than petrol, therefore the combustion is much smoother, and also cleaner. The engine will last longer when using Autogas. Oil and spark plugs will also last longer.

Your performance is also not greatly effected, however, you will notice that your miles to the gallon will decrease slightly.

> You get approximately 80 - 85% of the mileage that you normally get on petrol. For example - if 1 litre of petrol takes you 10 miles, then 1 litre of gas would do 8 - 8.5 miles. However, many converted cars do better than this.

Comment: I know it's just an example, but a 6.2l V8 will struggle to make it 5 miles on 1 liter of gas, let alone 10!

Comment: Lol, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 3):

Some engines rely on the lubricating effect of petrol on the valve seats, and need a modification to the cylinder heads. Depending on engine type, this could be a milling operation on the valve seats, or replacement of the seats and valves.

You'll need to know the exact engine type, to find out whether a head modification is necessary. A quick search shows it's probably the LS3. Holden used the LS3 in a [factory LPG conversion](http://performancedrive.com.au/2012-hsv-senator-signature-lpi-review-video-0613/). I've no idea what modifications they made though.

Performance depends on the LPG system used. Old-style LPG systems often resulted in a reduction in power. Modern LPI can get the same power level as petrol.

For completeness' sake: some engines can't be run on LPG. Recent engines from Ford and the VAG TSI are examples where LPG conversion companies have run tests but were unable to build a reliable system.

Comment: Another point is that LPG burns at higher temperatures and faster than petrol itself. This adds more load to pistons, crankshaft and lubrication. Sometimes modding a car to LPG have consumables: gas, oils, fluids, tyres and engine.

Comment: Is leaded gas still used in Turkey? If not, then there shouldn't be any problem (the "lubricating effect" being the deposition of lead on the valve seats). If so, then replacement heads should be easy to come by and would be a simple swap (far simpler than converting from petrol to LPG).